# Disable/ignore sound control from keyboard multimedia keys

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, keyboard

I have a Steelseries Apex 7 keyboard which has some liquid damage from a coca cola spill.
As a result the keyboards scroll wheel that controls sound level and muting is sending ghost presses to the PC and thus randomly muting and changing the sound.

Is there an option in the BIOS or in windows to ignore these keypresses or to ignore audio control inputs from the keyboard all together?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the keyboard?

Comment: I have completely disassembled the keyboard and cleaned it. Any further repairs would need replacement of components on the pcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will disable some audio volume keys:

```
Volume_Mute::
Volume_Down::
Volume_Up::
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:
[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
and especially
[Multimedia Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#multimedia).